# Escape string and get back string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to asp.net and I'm recently working on a mvc5 project. In that project there is a option for upload CSV file and download it back. Problem is  sometimes CSV file contain commas. I use this code to escape commas

```
Address = Address.Contains(",") ? string.Format("\"{0}\"", Address) :Address;
```

Now it save to database something like this
**""TEST,TEST STATION""**

After I retrieve back the data its contain double quotes like this
**"TEST,TEST STATION"**

How to remove double quotes? The method I used to escape comma is it correct or there is any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you just want to remove double quotes just use this code.

Address = Address.Contains("\"") ? Address.Replace("\"", string.Empty) : Address;

you will get the string without quotes. Even if you want to remove any characters in the given string you can use these regex expressions. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Checking whether the address contains any double quotes and then replacing all double quotes makes you iterate over the whole string twice, so I'd just skip the test and simply replace all instances, whether there are any or not.

Answer (score 1):

In between the lines I'm reading that you're building SQL statements by concatenating strings. You should avoid doing so, because such code is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if you don't get all the escaping rules exactly right, which is actually pretty hard.

There is a much better way: parameterized queries. You can find an example on how using `SqlCommand` and parameters [here](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries), or start reading on [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I don't know much about your code, but it might look something like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Addresses (Address) VALUES (@Address)";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
{
    cmd.Connection = dbConnection;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**Edit**:

That being said, removing quotes may be useful when parsing CSV, so here is a method to do just that:

```
private static string RemoveQuotes(string str)
{
    if (str.StartsWith("\"") && str.EndsWith("\""))
    {
        return str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Feel free to turn it into an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) if you prefer.